# Is it possible to create client and server component in the same file in NextJS 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my NextJS 13 app, one of my page.tsx files exports a component that can almost fully be rendered on the server. The only client interactivity it needs is a button that calls useRouter.pop() when it's clicked.

As far as I know, this means I need to create a new file with the "use client" directive just to export a client component that'll consist of just a button element. This seems like a inefficient way of creating a tiny component that will only be used in this one place. Is there any way of creating a client component within the page.tsx file?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately in Next.js there is no way of creating both a client and server rendering component in a single file.

> This seems like a inefficient way of creating a tiny component that will only be used in this one place.

The benefits of separating your server page.tsx and your tiny client component far outweighs the small inconvenience of having an extra file in your repository.

Comment: If you have a dynamic element that only appears on a single page, its sad to have to create a file just for that component. To me it sounds like a "problem" that it's not possible to have a alternative to `"use client"`.

Comment: @cglacet best we can do is start a discussion [in their official repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/categories/ideas)

Comment: In many cases it's easy to define client and server versions of a component having the same signature. It's also easy to detect whether you're in one environment or the other. So a pattern where both are defined in the same file, then the version that is exported is determined by the environment, would work well and provide a very good DX. Splitting them into separate files runs the risk of the consumer importing the client version within a server component (though not really the other way around), which would turn an SSG page into SSR unknowingly.